# Can I hide the "Note" and "Share" buttons in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: microsoft-edge

So, Windows 10 is out and their new web browser "Edge" doesn't seem like the worst thing in the World, but I can't seem to find the customization I'm used to.

Specifically I would like to hide/remove these buttons:
[image]

Any way to do that currently?

Bonus question: While making this question, I noticed that right clicking an image had neither a "show image" option nor a "copy address". How can I find the direct URL of an image in Microsoft Edge?

Comment: Just don't press the icons then...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no way to hide those buttons currently. The best way to request it is via the Windows Feedback app and/or the [Microsoft Edge forum on the Windows UserVoice](https://windows.uservoice.com/forums/285214-microsoft-edge).

The same applies to finding the URL of an image, though in the meantime you could use "Inspect Element" to get the URL out of the dev tools.

Comment: /r/softwaregore